# How to retrieve the typeahead element in angular?

Tags: angularjs, typeahead

I am building a content management system.

Fields are created by setting from a configuration file.

For example:

`<input ng-if="field.type == 'typeahead'" ng-attr-id="{{field.name}}" class="form-control" ng-model="frm_data[field.name]" uib-typeahead="test for test in testing($viewValue)" typeahead-wait-ms="250" />`

I need information from the element attribute, such as `"id"` (`field.name`).

May I know if it is possible to retrieve the element when `$scope.testing` is called?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Okay it's my dumb.

I used to try this:

```
uib-typeahead="test for test in testing($viewValue, {{field.name}})"
```

Netbeans shows the text inside the attribute in purple, which I think it is  a string. (Angular variable should be blue and white).

This works:

```
uib-typeahead="test for test in testing($viewValue, field.name)"
```

File closes. Thanks.